# How do i do use Jenkinsfile pipeline syntax for Espresso or Flutter for AWS DeviceFarm

Tags: flutter, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

How do i do use Jenkinsfile pipeline syntax for Espresso or Flutter for AWS DeviceFarm?
The plugin appears broken in a small way - when you try to use the snippet generator and tap custom for environment in "create run" you see a list of test specs - both custom if you created one and default per type of testing, appium, espresso, etc.

That drop down does not show up.  "Custom" did not work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the source code https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/awsdevicefarm/AWSDeviceFarmRecorder.java I find     private static final String CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT = "CustomEnvironment"; on line 214.
It's like an Easter Egg, using that exact string, and a string for a custom spec file I created in the console works.